# Creating an alias that is an incomplete command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-alias

The documentation from tldp.org doesn't really specify when or how the bash interpreter replaces an aliased string. I'm looking for information on how to create an alias that is an incomplete command.

```
alias quickscp="scp a.really.long.internal.domain.name:"
quickscp/data/testfile ./testfile
```

This fails - looks like bash doesn't expand `testalias` unless it is matching a string with whitespace (^/$ included I assume) surrounding it.

> It would be nice if aliases could assume some of the functionality of the C preprocessor, such as macro expansion,

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html agrees with me here - "it would be nice if" implies that it does not behave like a C preprocessor. Is there any way to force it? Something specific to the scp case above would solve my problem, but I'd be interested to know if there's a way to get the logic I'm trying to implement as well (for future hackery).

I guess this can be tl;dr'd to: How do I get bash to expand an alias if it isn't surrounded by whitespace?

Answer (score 4):

It's in the definition of a Bash alias that it is a separate word (cf. [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases)). I think what you want instead is a shell function:

```bsh
quickscp () {
  if [[ "$#" -ne 2 ]]; then echo "Need two arguments"; return 1; fi
  scp host.example.com:"$1" "$2"
  return "$?"
}
```

Call it like:

```
quickscp source target
```

As a bonus, you can do parameter checking and you'll get the return code of the `scp` command, so you can do `quickscp foo bar && echo "yay"` or similar chaining of commands.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with an alias. How about a function?

```
unalias quickscp
quickscp () (
   first="$1"
   shift
   exec scp "a.really.long.internal.domain.name:$first" "$@"
)
```

Notes:

- `unalias` because the portable definition of a function can collide with already defined alias.
- The function body is deliberately placed in a subshell to make the variable named `first` local, without a non-portable `local first` statement.
- `exec` because we no longer need the subshell after `scp` starts.

---

A completely different approach is to define a host in your SSH config (global: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`; user-specific: `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host foo
Hostname a.really.long.internal.domain.name
```

Then proceed like this:

```
scp foo:/data/testfile ./testfile
```

This will work with `ssh` or `scp`. It has nothing to do with aliases in a shell.

Comment: There is no point in `$@`, since there is only one `target` argument in `scp`.

Comment: @slhck I know. I wanted the approach to mimic a desired alias-like behavior for any command. Some other commands may make sense with `$@`.

Comment: Sure, I was going to do the same, but figured it wouldn't make a lot of sense, particularly when the options for scp (should the user want any) would have to be placed before the source/target. Good alternative with the hostname definition!

Answer (score 1):

One trick I know of is using en empty string as a delimiter for expansion:

```
quickscp""/data/testfile ./testfile
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I prefer this to the other answer just because it's quicker to write aliases that go to various depths, and it feels more temporary (my intent). Is this shell specific? I'm using `GNU bash 4.3.48`

Comment: I'm tried it in bash using Ubuntu on Windows and it worked for me. Seems like some bash difference.